# Use yq to substitute string in a yaml file

Tags: json, bash, shell, yq

I am trying to substitute all substrings in a yaml file with yq.

File:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: <SOME_NAME>
  name: <SOME_NAME>
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <SOME_NAME>
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: <SOME_NAME>
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: api
      containers:
        - image: some-docker-repo/<SOME_NAME>:latest
```

Right now I am using command like this:

```
yq e '
  .metadata.labels.app = "the-name-to-use" |
  .metadata.name = "the-name-to-use" |
  .spec.selector.matchLabels.app = "the-name-to-use" |
  .spec.template.metadata.labels.app = "the-name-to-use" |
  .spec.template.spec.containers[0].image |= sub("<SOME_NAME>", "the-name-to-use")
' template.yaml  > result.yaml
```

But I am sure it can be done as a one-liner. I tried using different variations of

```
yq e '.[] |= sub("<SOME_NAME>", "the-name-to-use")' template.yaml  > result.yaml
```

but I am getting error like

```
Error: cannot substitute with !!map, can only substitute strings. Hint: Most often you'll want to use '|=' over '=' for this operation.
```

Can you please suggest where I might have missed the point?

As an extra request, how would it look like if there would be 2 substitutions in template file?

e.x.  <SOME_NAME_1> and <SOME_NAME_2> that need to be substituted with some_var_1 and some_var_2 respectively.

Comment: `yq` does not recursive traversal function like `jq` which would be useful for your case. I guess you have to make use of what you have

Comment: Would you be interested in using the Python version of yq which uses jq as the underlying parser? ( I can attempt an answer in that)

Comment: @Inian meaning i'll need to have python installed to execute jq commands?

Comment: Python yq is a project on its own https://pypi.org/project/yq/ which uses jq to apply the operations on JSON and transcodes it back to YAML. Suggested that, since jq has much more powerful recursive operators than Go yq (the one you are using right now)

Comment: @inian yes if you can show it on jq that would be good.

Comment: Using the above said Python exec, you could do `yq -Y 'reduce (paths | select(.[-1] == "app" or .[-1] == "name")) as $p ( .; setpath($p; "new")  )' yaml`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to use '..' to match all the nodes, then filter out to only include strings

```
yq e ' (.. | select(tag == "!!str")) |= sub("<SOME_NAME>", "the-name-to-use")' template.yaml
```

Disclosure: I wrote yq

Comment: That is a working solution, thank you! 
Do you think you can come up with an extension where we need to process 2 substitutions? e.x. <SOME_NAME_1> and <SOME_NAME_2>

Comment: You can just pipe in another update: `(.. | select(tag == "!!str")) |= sub("<SOME_NAME>", "the-name-to-use") | (.. | select(tag == "!!str")) |= sub("<SOME_FIELD>", "meow-meow")`